# Measuring wasted time in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, metrics

Is there a way to measure how much time each subprocess of a `multiprocessing.Pool` spends waiting for input vs. how much time they spend crunching data?

Let's take this simple example that processes a file's lines in parallel:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=16)
with open('a_large_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for foo in pool.imap_unordered(a_slow_function, f, chunksize=100)
        do_something_with(foo)
```

Depending on how long `a_slow_function` takes, how fast we can read from `f`, and the chunk size, my subprocesses could end up twiddling their thumbs while waiting for data. Can I measure this?

My best guess so far is to wrap `cProfile.runctx` around `a_slow_function`. This yields one profile file per worker, which I could then compare with the total run time of the script. However, `do_something_with(foo)` can skew the results, so I would have to take that into account. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Note: I don't mind if the solution involves linux-specific tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `line_profiler`, a line profiler, to get the time for the

```
for foo in pool.imap_unordered(a_slow_function, f, chunksize=100)
```

line and the sum time inside `a_slow_function` and then compare *those* two numbers.

I'm not sure if it's a *good* idea, but it's an idea nonetheless.

---

You could also just try timing things seperately, such as seeing how quickly you can read the lines in the file:

eg.

```
for line in f: pass
```